# How to look behind the curtains of Grails?

Tags: grails

I'm reading through an introductory Grails book and I saw this code:

```
if (session.user) { ... }
```

`session` is a `GrailsHttpSession` which extends `HttpSession`, neither of which have a `user` property.  I wanted to figure out how setting/getting an arbitrary property was working, so I set some breakpoints and discovered after a while that `HttpSession` is enhanced in `ServletsGrailsPluginSupport`.

My question is, setting breakpoints and stepping through the code is a slow, brute-force method of discovering how the Grails magic is working.  Is there a faster, more efficient way to discover how and where Grails is enhancing ordinary methods?  (For example, I still have no idea where `DomainEntity.findAllByInsertFieldHere` is implemented and no idea how to find it.)

To be clear, I'm not asking to be given a fish, I'm asking how to fish.

Comment: Use the source young jedi: https://github.com/grails/grails-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely check out [Programming Grails by Burt Beckwith](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024750.do). The description says:

> Dig deeper into Grails architecture and discover how this application
>   framework works its magic. Written by a core developer on the Grails
>   team, this practical guide takes you **behind the curtain** to reveal
>   the inner workings of its 2.0 feature set.

Well shoot, that's exactly what you're looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

While there is a lot to be said for reading various books out there, none of them will in fact be able to give you the view of Grails that the [API](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/) or [source code](https://github.com/grails/grails-core) will.

Take the time to browse through the API for both Grails and Spring and take a look at how things are implemented in the source code.

That will give you the best understanding of 'what's inside'.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy uses a lot of meta programming, every class has a meta-class in that meta class you can add functionalities or modify functionalities to the class, you can even create dynamic methods, for example `findAllByInsertFieldHere` doesn't really exist, but if a method  starts with `findAllBy`, the it uses the rest of the function as a parameters in this case `insertFieldHere` to create the query.

Check this: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Method+Invokation